# Formula field - Trying to show a flag if checkbox = true

Tags: formula-field, checkbox, image-formula, boolean

I am trying to create a formula to show a red flag if a checkbox field is set to True

This is the current formula

```
(IF("Response Timer Failed" = TRUE, IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "red", 30, 30),""))
```

This is the error I am getting and I am unsure about how to resolve.

> Incorrect parameter type for operator '='. Expected Text, received Boolean

Please advise, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `field API Name` instead of label name (`Response Timer Failed`) in the formula field.

your formula should be like below and the formula return type should be `text`

```
IF(Response_Timer_Failed__c = TRUE, IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "red", 30, 30),"")
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, what a rookie move haha cheers

Comment: @asidrey PS A Boolean value is already true/false, you don't need `= TRUE` here.